# How can I obtain horizontal data entry fields in a django template using the formset?

Tags: django, templates, formset

I have the following template, which produces a form with vertical data entry fields. Please guide me to achieve 'horizontal' data entry fields.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BUDGET</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>BUDGET MANAGEMENTS</p>
<p>Your Account Number is : {{ account_number }}.</p> <p>You Chose {{ period }} {{month}} as period<p>   
{% if form.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">
Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
</p>
{% endif %} 
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table>
{% for form in formset.forms %}
{{ form }}
{% endfor %}
</table>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233929/horizontal-per-row-forms-in-a-django-formset

Answer (score 1):

See [*Displaying a form using a template*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) from Django doc. It contains the exact guide how to control rendering of your form. Something like:

```
<table>
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <tr>
    {% for field in form %}
       <td>
         {{ field.errors }}
         {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
       </td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through CSS and not by just form rendering. You need to create inline form elements.
May be you can take look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) CSS library or such similar library.