# Display multiple rows as grid in django template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I need to display a few rows from database to user. For example I have table `Fruits` with columns: `name`, `color`, `price`. So I want my form generate the html like compact grid view:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apples</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
    <td>100$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>pears</td>
    <td>green</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I found workaround with formset as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234286/3872976) question:

```python
class Fruit(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    color = CharField(max_length=100)
    price = CharField(max_length=100)

FruitFormSet = modelformset_factory(Fruit, form=FruitForm)
form = FruitFormSet(queryset=Fruit.objects.all())
```

This is kinda cool, but there's a ton of code and it looks a bit clumsy. I wonder if I can do something similar with django crispy forms.

**So my question is**:

What is the best way to display multiple rows from table in django? I don't need to provide to user a way to edit it. Should I use forms as all? Or I just need to pass dictionary of objects to a template, iterate over it and add html tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms are for editing. Since you don't need to edit the values, you can simply pass a queryset in a context dictionary to your template. An example would be:

**views.py**

```
def fruit_list(request):
    context = {'fruit_list': Fruit.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'fruits/fruit_list.html', context)
```

**fruits/fruit_list.html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  {% for fruit in fruit_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ fruit.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ fruit.color }}</td>
    <td>{{ fruit.price }}$</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```