# Django framework, crud in grid row

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, html-table, crud

I’ve been developing an app in djanog 3.0 for my wife. Got a nice modal ajax crud up and running for the grid, but she does not like the modal effect, she just wants to edit inside the row and always have an empty row at the bottom for new entries.

I’ve looked at table2 and jqgrid but have not been able to find something that works like that. I’ve now been playing around with editablegrid.net js grid and I can display data and edit, but not save the edited data. Editablegrid is a good example of what my wife would like to do, without the empty new row, but should be able to hack that in.

Obviously I’ll not be able to make a row a from, so I need to figure out how to make my data serial in something like json. I then also need the CSRF token as part of the json right?

I’m way out of my depth as I develop embedded c for a living and this all is self taught as we go.

Questions are:
What is the best grid for something like this? Is it even possible?
Is django even suited for something like this?
Should I pivot and go with rest api and look at some other tech like react?

EDIT 1:
I tried @Raiyan suggestion like follows:

```
{% for person in persons %}
<form id="F{{ person.pk}}" method="post" action="{% url 'person-update' person.pk %}" class="js-ajax-update-form" update-table-name="ajax-table">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ person.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.id_number }}</td>
  </tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

but if I open page and look at html it looks like this:

```
<form method="post"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="IREdUDr8bplgvDrtmMSSjOua2NL98SXnoeIGdX1mN0nY2hpQTByW0FfJZxvO5kCw">
<tr id="R2">
    <td>Mr.</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
        <td>123456789</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

For some reason the form tag gets closed before the table row and input.  I've also adapted a simple [CRUD books app](https://github.com/digenaldo/django-crud-example) to try and get the desired behavior with none of the fluf, but there also the form tag closes immediately.
For the CRUD app I changed the fbv view to:

```
def book_list(request, template_name='books_fbv/book_list.html'):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    forms = []
    for index, book in enumerate(books):
        forms.append(BookForm(request.POST or None, instance=book, prefix="form_{}".format(index)))
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = forms

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for form in forms:
            if form.is_valid():
                action = form.save(commit=False)
                action.save()
    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

and html to:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for book in object_list %}
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ book.name }}</td>  
            <td>{{ book.pages }}</td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea why form tags close like that?

Comment: Not only the <form> tag is closing, the `id`, `method`, `action` etc. attributes are not appearing in the rendered HTML. Is this all you see in the page source?

Comment: Hi @Raiyan.  For the CRUD test app I added an id="P{{ book.instance.id }}" and that seems to add into the html but still the form tag closes before the row.  After some sleep I'll try this guys post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233929/horizontal-per-row-forms-in-a-django-formset I just can't believe it is so difficult.  Maybe because I'm not in the web development mind set

Answer (score 0):

Django is very well suited for projects like this.

> Obviously I’ll not be able to make a row a from

I think you can, unless I misunderstood something. You can render each row as a separate form, using Django templates. The implementation may look like this:

```
{% for row in rows %}
<form method="post">
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  ...
</tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

You are right that you need to handle the CSRF token. Django allows you to insert CSRF token anywhere in the rendered HTML using the `{% csrf_token %}` in your template. A very simple form would look like this:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}... </form>
```

In your case, each of the row-forms would then look like:

```
{% for row in rows %}
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  ...
</tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Read more about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had no idea you could do something like this!  It might just work well for what I would like to achieve because I can get the row in my js which means I can get its parent which is the form and then I can just submit that in the same way I would have done for my modal code (which rendered a modal with a form on).  Hopefully I can test this tonight and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything that @Raiyan said, but just wanted to give my input on this as well.

> she just wants to edit inside the row and always have an empty row at the bottom for new entries.

Sounds like your wife wants something very responsive and dynamic, which for me, it means that the frontend (or client-side) should be more active. Although you can achieve a similar result with Django or other "server render" options, using Rest API and Javascript will give you much more flexibility.

React is an example (as you mentioned), but depending on your project, you don't need to go there. You can still use Django to create your API and simple Javascript (or even jQuery) to call the API. This would allow you to create new rows dynamically, delete data and manipulate the content without reloading the page (which I believe is the smooth effect desired).

Here are some references:

AJAX in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Rest API in Django: https://medium.com/@BennettGarner/build-your-first-rest-api-with-django-rest-framework-e394e39a482c

Comment: I might need to go this way anyway, but already have a lot of features done, but if I understand rest api, it might be the future if I would like to develop the site into an app.  If I understand correctly, having most of the models setup correctly, creating a rest API later should not be to big of an issue, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you wanna go to the app direction, rest API would the way to go. And having your models and everything done will help with the API anyway